# How to prevent navigation bar to active icons flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using navigation bar in flutter when I am moving from first index to third it first moves to second then to the third (for milliseconds only and show active icons).
How can I turn off this behavior of bottom navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

This is a way:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 5,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedLabelStyle: kBottomSelectedText,
          unselectedLabelStyle: kBottomUnSelectedText,
          fixedColor: kBlack,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
              print(selectedIndex);
            });
          },
          currentIndex: selectedIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Home',
              icon: Image.asset(
                kHomeUnSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                kHomeSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'My Jobs',
              icon: Image.asset(
                kMyJobSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                kMyJobSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Trans History',
              icon: Image.asset(
                kTransactionHistoryUnSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                kTransactionHistorySelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Inbox',
              icon: Image.asset(
                kInboxUnSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                kInboxSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Profile',
              icon: Image.asset(
                kProfileUnSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              activeIcon: Image.asset(
                kProfileSelected,
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to solve it with this.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.